# help me with this demonstration of the form p → q

Tags: logic

good morning, my question is about a demonstration of the form p → q.

If $a> 0 → (a + 4)^2>a^2 +16$

I am recently learning to demonstrate, I am self-taught and I did not have anyone to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For *any* $a$, we have $(a+4)^2 \operatorname{\mathbf {=}} a^2+8a+16$

Now if we assume $a>0$ then...